# Zookeeper can't be started because of missing zookeeper-gc.log

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a 3-node `systemd` kafka cluster. I had removed all log files in `/opt/kafka/kafka/logs/` in 1 node, thought they were just storage-consuming logs. Now after restarting the `zookeeper.service` I get the following error form `systemctl status zookeeper.service` which makes it unable to start:

```
systemd[1]: Started zookeeper.service.
zookeeper-server-start.sh[23029]: [0.001s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': Permission denied
zookeeper-server-start.sh[23029]: [0.002s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log' using options 'filecount=10,filesize=100M' failed.
zookeeper-server-start.sh[23029]: Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*:file=/opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M', see error log for details.
zookeeper-server-start.sh[23029]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
zookeeper-server-start.sh[23029]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And therefore `kafka.service` can't be started since it requires `zookeeper.service`.

I have tried to create the `zookeeper-gc.log` manually and configured the owner, group, and permissions based on other nodes' same log file:

```
touch /opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log
chown kafka:kafka /opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log
chmod 644 /opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log
```

And restarted both services but got the same output.
I also find the following lines in `/opt/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh`:

```
KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xlog:gc*:file=$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M"
KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSi
```

But had not enogh knowledge to modify or change them.
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Please add information about OS.

Comment: My cluster is running on Ubuntu 20.04 @Sinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message of your `systemctl restart kafka zookeeper` command's output, it seems either permissions or ownership of either the `/opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log` file or the `/opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/` directory is not correct.

I don't know which OS you're running, but try the following and see if it fixes the problem:

```bash
chown -R kafka:kafka /opt/kafka/kafka/bin/../logs/
```

**Note**: The `-R` flag means `recursive`.